# Formularios reactivos, model driven, etc (Angular 2/4)

Tags: angularjs-2.0, formularios, model

Tengo implementados formularios reactivos o model driven como suelen llamarlos en mi proyecto de Angular 4... No sé si los conceptos tengo mal entendidos, de ser así que alguien me corrija... Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué cuando cambio el type de los input a date, time, number o cualquiera que no sea text deja de funcionar correctamente este tipo de formularios?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, sin codigo ni demos es muy dificil responderte, ya que si no te funciona es porque tendras algun error, pues debería funcionar con diferentes tipos.

Hay dos tipos de formularios en Angular, **reactive forms y template-model driven form**, uno es reactivo y se controla desde el código:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html

Mientras el otro está más enfocado a poner las reglas de validación en el html:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#template-driven-forms